# Speech Priming for non-US LUIS Apps

Tags: botframework

the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-speech-priming?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 says "Priming is not supported from non U.S. regional LUIS apps including: eu.luis.ai and au.luis.ai" - is that a permanent restriction or will it be opened to eu.luis.ai etc soon?

Comment: This is probably a question that should be asked on the Cognitive services UserVoice page(https://cognitive.uservoice.com/)

Comment: As far as I can see, cognitive.uservoice.com doesn't cover this, as Speech Priming is a Bot Service feature.  I posted feedback on the Azure Bot Service topic at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/562027-azure-bot-service/suggestions/36816418-speech-priming-for-non-us-luis-apps